# Set current displayed row for UIPickerView

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview

How to set current row as 3rd or another row after UIPickerView rows loaded?
There is always example for selecting a curtain row. Thank you.

```
@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerViewForDetail;
```

Comment: Can you explain it better, maybe on example ? You want to have current row not be displayed as selected ?

Comment: For example a normal pickerview displays first row as selected. But I want to show 3rd or other rows, not the first default row as selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    [pickerViewForDetail selectRow:yourRowNumber inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```